# uglifyjs - symfony assetic dump, path to node

Tags: javascript, node.js, symfony, assetic

I'm able to use uglifyjs locally on my ubuntu dev server, however when using the remote Centos machine for production I get the following error when running

```
$ php app/console assetic:dump
```

which returns a `[RuntimeException]`

> Path to node executable could not be resolved.

I believe both node and uglifyjs are installed if i run

```
$ which node 
  /usr/bin/nodejs
$ which uglifyjs 
  /usr/bin/uglifyjs
```

my `config.yml` part is below

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
  debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
  use_controller: false
  bundles:        [eventsBundle]

  node: /usr/bin/nodejs
  filters:
    uglifyjs2:
    # the path to the uglifyjs executable
    bin: /usr/bin/uglifyjs
```

I have also tried

```
...
  bin: /usr/lib/node_modules/uglify-js 
...
```

Comment: strangely if I remove the 'node: /usr/bin/nodejs' from the config.yml and do 'php app/console assetic:dump' it works for dev. if I then try it for production e.g 'php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod' I get the same error as before

Comment: ok solution was to remove 'node: /usr/bin/nodejs' so the system guesses the nodejs path.  Then make sure you clear the cache for production, then do the assets instal for production as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

**config.yml** as below

```
# Assetic Configuration
  assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: "%kernel.debug%"
    bundles:        [eventsBundle]

    filters:
      uglifyjs2:
      # the path to the uglifyjs executable
      bin: /usr/bin/uglifyjs
```

in terminal first run

```
$ php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

then

```
$ php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got this issue recently. I put here in case someone needed.
Firstly, What you need to do is to **run the uglifyjs directly** from the command prompt and see if it's broken.

Secondly, make sure your configuration pointing to the right file. In my case, the newer version resides in another folder `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, while in config it's pointed to `/usr/lib/node_modules`. So by creating a link to local lib solve my problem.